# WCF Configurations

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, configuration

I am working through a REST services book dealing with WCF. I have been following along the examples and relize that the configuration of WCF seems like a tough thing to master. I have a piece of code below and configures and opens an endpoint. I know that this is an old school 3.0 way to accomplish this RESTful task but am wondering how I could set this up in the app config instead any ideas? Also does anyone know any sites that breakdown the WCF configurations in code/config in a reasonable manner? Most places I have been looking show only specific examples.

```
        CustomBinding b = new CustomBinding();
        TextMessageEncodingBindingElement msgEncoder = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        msgEncoder.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.None;
        b.Elements.Add(msgEncoder);
        HttpTransportBindingElement http = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
        b.Elements.Add(http);
        ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleHTTPService));
        ServiceEndpoint se = sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(SimpleHTTPService),
        b,
        "http://localhost:8889/TestHttp");
        sh.Open();
```

Comment: WCF 4 allows you to do this without the code above or having to mess with the web/app.config.

Comment: Like it says ...  I know that this is an old school 3.0 way to accomplish this RESTful task but am wondering how I could set this up in the app config instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define that endpoint in config, it would look like the config below. Notice that this isn't enough to emulate the REST programming model in 3.0 (remember that this only sets the binding; on 3.5 and above you only need to set a behavior)

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="OldStylePox">
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="None" />
        <httpTransport />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="USE_THE_FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAME_OF_SimpleHttpService">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8889/TestHttp"
                binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="OldStylePox"
                contract="USE_THE_FULLY_QUALIFIED_NAME_OF_SimpleHttpService" />
    </service>
  </services>
<system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos, can you say more about why I will need to set a behavior? Are we talking about service/enpoint behavior or both here?

Comment: That would be an endpoint behavior. The support for non-SOAP endpoints in WCF/.NET 3.0 was **really bad**. Can't you use 3.5? If you can use that, than you can use a `<webHttp/>` *endpoint* behavior for your endpoint.